# Retrieve Data from Firebase and Save It on the Android local Database

Tags: android, firebase

Can anyone help me how to retrieve data from firebase and save it on a local android database, so that I can search data offline.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow please show us your effort, what you tried before to get help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firebase is meant to be used a a replacement for any local SQLite databases. It can be searched while offline, as well. If you're using the Realtime Database, check [these docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities). If you're using Firestore, check [these docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) instead.

Comment: yes, but it's in the form of a cache, if I want to retrieve all the data that is in Firebase and stored locally so that users can use it offline, for example a dictionary application

Comment: sorry, i just found out about firestore, what if the data that is on firestore can be retrieved and stored in sqlite

Comment: I am making an Android dictionary application using Firebase, which where data in Firebase will be stored in SQLite, and there is an update on Firebase so that the local database can synchronize with the server.

Comment: When you're using Realtime Database or Firestore, a copy of all the data is stored on each user's phone automatically by the SDK. If you follow the docs I linked to, you can instruct Realtime Database or Firestore to cache all of that data for offline use in the app.